# How to decide whether a table in the database exists or not?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I am trying to update a database table and the table's name format is employee_yearName_monthName. because I want to keep each month's data on a  separate table.

Now at the start of the month there is no table for that month. SO i should create the table. But the question is how to decide whether the table exists or not?

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain why you don't want to use columns for `year` and `month` in a single table `employee`?

Comment: yahh that may be a bad design. But when you are working on a existing project , you can't change the design of the database. you need to find a solution with existing tables. I am in such a situation actuall

Answer (score 2):

`I want to keep each month's data on a separate table`

This is seriously BAD design! If you have **huge** amounts of data (at least in the range of 50-100GB, around a hundred million rows), rather prefer **Partitioning** (-->[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm), -->[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html). If you don't have that much data, just don't worry, store the data in one table, with the proper columns, and set up proper indexes!

Why is this a bad design? Just think about these:

- How would you formulate a query for example a yearly report for all users?
- What if a user has 32 character name? Your table names will be too long for example for Oracle to handle
- How do you formulate queries about weeks that have one half in one month, the other in the next one?

**EDIT** as OP disclosed more details
Solutions

- you can refactor the database - that needs management decision. You should evaluate the costs associated with maintaining the current structure vs refactoring the DB, and present this to decision takers...
- in Oracle, you can use the [`USER_TABLES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5443.htm) management table to query for table names: `SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'employeeName%` for example.

Comment: yahh that may be a bad design. But when you are working on a existing project , you can't change the design of the database. you need to find a solution with existing tables. I am in such a situation actually  :D :D

Comment: @DebobrotoDas updated answer to convey solution for your problem, but I must say, that even if getting this through management is a seriously rough ride, you'll thank yourself after you hae done it - from all points of views, including, but not limited to your professional reputation and future career...

Comment: thanks. I think the management is not going to change the design :D :D . because already more than a million user is working with that design. and management cant change that design suddenly. The clients will just kick us : D:D

Comment: @DebobrotoDas: There are things you can do to smooth a transition across schema, if you plan properly.  Views, for example, can help a lot.  As can a second database which synchronises with your current one through appropriate translations.  This isn't the first time that a terrible database design has needed to be fixed, but I completely agree with ppeterka that it is in serious need.

Comment: @DebobrotoDas I know this situation. All you need is data to back up your arguments. And the data needs to show the amount of hard cash ($$$) this change will save for the company. Get tough, this will be a rough ride, but if you can pull this move, it's almost sure that you will get promoted. Eggyal is right: there are plenty of options to support seamless migration. You could even show this thread to them :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, this is not a good design. However, if you want to stick with your design you could just use

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename ( ... )
```

Comment: if data is inserted in the table too frequently in a day, then how many times you will check that "if not exists'. Is there not a  more clear solution?

Comment: @DebobrotoDas Then you can do `SELECT 1 FROM tablename LIMIT 1` and you will get either a row or an error.

Comment: @carlos, I can get error for some other reasons also. Then how to decide that the error is happening due to non existence of the table?